# I want to calculate a area of NDWI for a region for each month over for 10 years in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I want to calculate a area of NDWI for a region for each month over for 10 years in Google earth engine. I have a starting date and Ending date array for every month for each year.Using Image collection function I need calculate NDWI and its area for the image availability month and add it in a array. If image not available for a month then add zero in the array and so on.

Here is the Link for my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/322b02e03dffed8d02327eef3474c1d9

```
function comps(yearArray, SD, ED) {
  var collection = [];
  for (var idx = 0; idx < SD.length; idx++) {
    var year = SD[idx].split('-')[0];
    var month = SD[idx].split('-')[1];
    var Date = year + '-' + month;
    timeseries.Year.push(Date);
    if (year <= 2013) {
      var SD_1 = SD[idx];
      var ED_1 = ED[idx];
      collection = colLT5.filterDate(SD_1, ED_1)
        .filterBounds(ER)
        .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 10));
      var Count = collection.size();
      Image_count.push(Count);
      if (Count.gt(0)) {
        Map.addLayer(collection.mosaic().clip(ER), vizParams_L5, 'FCC_' + year, false);
        var NDWIcomp_L5 = collection.map(NDWI_L5).mosaic().clip(ER);
        var L5_Aqua = NDWIcomp_L5.updateMask(NDWIcomp_L5.gte(-0.1));
        Map.addLayer(L5_Aqua, {
          bands: 'NDWI',
          min: -1,
          max: 1,
          palette: ['#eff3ff', '#bdd7e7', '#6baed6', '#3182bd', '#08519c']
        }, 'NDWI_' + year, false);

        var Water_Count_L5 = Pixel_Count(L5_Aqua);
        var ndwi_area_L5 = (Water_Count_L5.multiply(900)).divide(1000000);
        timeseries.Area.push(ndwi_area_L5);
      } else {
        timeseries.Area.push(0);
      }
```

This is the relevant part of code. If the collection.size()>0 then calculate NDWI and area. Push the area in the Area array otherwise zero value to be pushed in the area for that date

Comment: Please include the relevant chunk of code and a complete description of the error/problem in the body of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Code you write in Earth Engine often look quite different from what many are used to. You have to keep track of which code is evaluated server-side and client-side, which can be tricky. To simplify things, it's often best to try to stick to only server-side code, as far as possible at least. That, amongst other things, means no for or while loops and no if statements.

Below is a take on how you might solve your problems the "Earth Engine way". It probably doesn’t do exactly what you want, but it's hopefully a starting point:

```
var region = Map.getBounds(true)
var startDate = ee.Date('1997-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2016-01-01')

var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .select(['B2', 'B4', 'pixel_qa'], ['green', 'nir', 'pixel_qa'])

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .select(['B3', 'B5', 'pixel_qa'], ['green', 'nir', 'pixel_qa'])

var ndwiCollection = l5.merge(l8)
  .filterBounds(region)
  .map(function (image) {
    return image
      .select([]).addBands( // Replace bands to keep properties
        image.normalizedDifference(['green', 'nir'])
      )
      .updateMask(landsatMask(image))
      .rename('NDWI')
  })

var monthCount = endDate.difference(startDate, 'months').round()
var monthlyNdwi = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, monthCount.subtract(1))
    .map(function (monthsOffset) {
      var start = startDate.advance(monthsOffset, 'months')
      var end = start.advance(1, 'months')
      var ndwi = selectOrEmpty(ndwiCollection
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .median(), ['NDWI']
      )
      var water = ndwi.gte(-0.1).selfMask()
      return ee.Feature(null, {
        'area': area(water),
        'month': start.format('MMM'),
        'year': start.format('yyyy'),
        'system:time_start': start.millis()
      })

    })
  )

print(monthlyNdwi)

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.groups({
  features: monthlyNdwi, 
  xProperty: 'year', 
  yProperty: 'area', 
  seriesProperty: 'month'
})
print(chart)


function selectOrEmpty(image, bands) {
  var defaults = ee.Image(
    ee.List(bands).iterate(function (bandName, acc) { 
      return ee.Image(acc).addBands(
        ee.Image().rename(ee.String(bandName))
      )
    }, ee.Image([]))
  )
  return image.addBands(defaults).select(bands)
}


function area(image) {
  return ee.Image.pixelArea()
    .updateMask(image.mask())
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
      geometry: region, 
      scale: 30
    }).get('area')
}


function landsatMask(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
  var clean = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 1)
  var water = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 2)
  return clean.or(water)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/82ccbf6725374e053238fbc4f942c696

Comment: Thank you so much!!!